# Type safety - GO vs C pointers

Tags: programming-languages, c, pointers, go, type-safety

C is a static-typed language that is not type-safe, because pointers(`void *y`) let you do pretty much anything you like, even things that will crash your program.

GO is also a static typed language

Despite, GO has pointers(`var y *int`), it is still considered type-safe language.

---

Question:

Considering GO pointers,

Why GO language is called type-safe language?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few differences between Go and C that makes the former at least more type safe:

1. Unless you muck about with the [unsafe](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) package, you're not going to crash a Go program (in the sense that it won't do something that causes the OS to kill it). You may cause it to panic, but this is not the same thing as a crash (and it is recoverable).
2. Go does not have pointer arithmetic ([source](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1)) -- although it does have null reference of sort called [`nil`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983118/what-does-nil-mean-in-golang).
3. Go's `void*` equivalent, `interface{}`,  is cast in a more safe manner using [type assertions](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15), which will not just crash and permit safer type testing, or type switches.

Basically Go and languages with similar mixes of declared types and runtime types (C# and Java) are type safe because they supplement an unsound type system with a runtime type system that turns type errors that would have caused crashes into runtime exceptions.

C has an unsound type system and no runtime system that would prevent unsafe behavior.

Some languages, like [ATS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATS_(programming_language)), also like runtime protections but are type-safe because their type systems make illegal operations unsayable.

Basically: *type safe* means the language won't let you do anything illegal.

Sometimes the runtime stops you (like in dynamic languages like Python).

Sometimes the type system stops you.

For Go it is a combination of both.

Answer (score 6):

The lack of type safety doesn't come from pointers - it comes from `void` pointers and the ability to perform arbitrary casts between pointer types. There's nothing non-type safe about "pointer to integer" - the lack of type safety in C comes about because there's no guarantee that an `int*` is *actually* pointing to some memory which contains an integer.

Comment: So, Do you mean, GO compiler does not allow type casting( like `*char` to `*Person`)?

Comment: Correct - well, unless you're messing around with `unsafe` and `Pointer` in which case you deserve everything you get in terms of blowing up the type system.

Comment: Arbitrary casts without safety checks (or, whose only safety checks are compile-time and easily defeated).  Also, lack of type safety comes from  unchecked pointer arithmetic, independent of casting, as this allows moving the pointer off of what it started at; so, may end up referring to arbitrary memory.  Of course, pointer arithmetic can be combined with casting!